# Dynamically add to the screen input fields and sum their (numeric) content in ionic cordova (angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, mobile, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic and angularjs. Wanted to be able to insert the following input filed dynamically when Insert is clicked.

```
<div class="list">

  <div class="item item-input-inset">
    <label class="item-input-wrapper">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Add">
    </label>
    <button class="button button-small">
      Insert
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

and keep a running total off all the input numbers to add them at the end

Comment: I am trying to figure out the code that I would need to add to app.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

1. create an array for your list `numbers: []`
2. use `ng-repeat` inside `ion-list` on the numbers array
3. create a method for summing all numbers.

One point could be improved in my code and that is that insert is always adding the new item at the end of the list. If you'd like to add it after the clicked `insert` button you'd need to pass `$index` as parameter to insert method and use `splice` to add the new item at the correct position.

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/zbjc9ndf/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', ['ionic'])
    .controller('mainController', MainController);

function MainController() {
    var vm = this,
        defaultNumberObj = {
            value: 0
        };
    
    angular.extend(this, {
        numbers: [angular.copy(defaultNumberObj)],
        insert: function () {
            console.log('inserting...');
            vm.numbers.push({
                value: 0
            });
        },
        removeLast: function() {
         if (vm.numbers.length > 1)
                vm.numbers.pop(1);
        },
        reset: function() {
         vm.numbers = [angular.copy(defaultNumberObj)];
        },
        calcSum: function () {
            var sum = 0;
            angular.forEach(vm.numbers, function (number) {
                sum += parseInt(number.value) || 0;
            });
            return sum;
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.1.0/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.1.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController as ctrl">
<ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="button button-icon icon ion-ios-minus-outline"
          ng-click="ctrl.removeLast()"></button>
      </div>
      <h1 class="title">Result {{ctrl.calcSum()}}</h1>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="button" ng-click="ctrl.reset()">
            Reset
        </button>
      </div>
    </ion-header-bar>
<ion-content class="has-header">
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-repeat="number in ctrl.numbers">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Add" ng-model="number.value" />
            <button class="button button-small" ng-click="ctrl.insert()">Insert</button>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>total: {{ctrl.calcSum()}}</ion-content>
  </div>
```

Comment: Great job this gives me exactly what I wanted, exceeded my expectations

Comment: also how can i focus on the just inserted input text

Comment: You can add a `autofocus` directive. Please have a look in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zbjc9ndf/7/). To see it in action you have to open the fiddle in [fullscreen mode](https://jsfiddle.net/zbjc9ndf/7/embedded/result/).

Comment: Thank you so much I'm learning a lot from you. also I was trying to get the new input to insert after the one that was clicked but cannot make it happen. i am not sure how to insert the commands to shift the fields.

Comment: You're welcome. I've added it to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zbjc9ndf/8/). For more examples to `splice`. Have a look at [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). MDN is a great resource for learning javascript.